# Путь сдодержит недопустимы знаки при обращении в ресурсы

Tags: c#, winforms, xml

В коде подключаю xml файл к программе

```
XDocument.Load(Properties.Resources.users);
```

(где 'users' - название xml дока).

И получаю ошибку: System.ArgumentException: "Путь содержит недопустимые знаки."

Comment: А что у вас в этом `Properties.Resources.users` лежит-то? Там точно путь к файлу?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, я обращяюсь к файлу users который лежит в ресурсах проекта

Comment: Ну так вы проверьте-то что там лежит и что ожидает метод Load...

Comment: Это как бы название переменной, вам нужно посмотреть, что же в ней лежит.

Comment: @PavelMayorov,
Извините за тупой вопрос. Как посмотреть?

Comment: Отладчиком. Или отладочным выводом: меняете тип проекта на консольный и используете Console.WriteLine

Comment: @PavelMayorov лучше заставить человека потратить 15 минут на то чтобы научится пользоваться отладчиком, чем предложить ему дебажить выводом в консоль 

Comment: @iiKuzmychov ну, отладчик не всегда справляется, поэтому отладочный вывод тоже нужно уметь использовать. Но в целом согласен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы добавляете файл в ресурсы проекта, его содержимое попадает в одноимённое свойство как текст. Иными словами, ваш `Properties.Resources.users` содержит текст XML документа, в то время как метод `XDocument.Load` ожидает путь к файлу. Отсюда и ошибка, тот самый недопустимый знак из сообщения об ошибке - это `<`.

Проще всего будет исправить ошибку заменив Load на Parse:

```cs
XDocument.Parse(Properties.Resources.users);
```

Однако, в таком случае вам придётся внимательно следить за кодировкой файла, потому что такой способ чтения не совсем корректен. Кодировка XML стандартно указывается в директиве `<?xml`, а автогенерированный код по умолчанию считывает всё в кодировке по умолчанию.

Поэтому правильный способ считать XML из ресурсов требует, чтобы вы изменили в настройках ресурсов проекта способ представления файла со строкового на бинарный. В таком случае ваш `Properties.Resources.users` станет массивом байт. и сможет быть считан следующим способом:

```cs
XDocument.Load(new MemoryStream(Properties.Resources.users));
```

Отмечу, что этот способ не устраняет проблему с кодировками, а просто позволяет указать правильную кодировку в самом файле.

---

Наконец, если вам хочется избежать копирования данных в промежуточный массив байт, есть смысл читать из потока напрямую. К сожалению, стандартный кодогенератор "уговорить" отдать вам поток не получится, поэтому придётся проигнорировать созданное им свойство и залезть напрямую в ResourceManager:

```cs
XDocument.Load(Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("users", Properties.Resources.Culture));
```